How to clamp Vdiff of LM317HV or TL783 regulator
I am using a transformer that supports my current requirement, but produces a voltage higher than the Max. voltage of the regulator in use. I have seen others use Zeners across the input/outputs of a regulator to limit the Vdiff of it. I have tried this, but it affects the regulation at higher voltages. Please explain what might be happening here, or other approaches that might be employed.



Show your circuit

What do you expect the Zener diode to do when input voltage is high and output is low?

@mike can you provide a higher resolution schematic? That one is hard to read. Please ask a specific question.

Where is the transformer in the schematic?

The transformer has nothing to do with the question, which is:  How to clamp Vdiff of a LM317HV or TL783 regulator. To be clear; the voltage across the input to out put of the regulator. Thank You

By clamping such that the regulator's \$V_{OUT} - V_{IN} < V_{MAXDIFF}\$, when the input rises far enough to invoke the clamp, then the clamp will "pull" the output upwards in potential too, beyond the desired regulated voltage. I'm sure that's not what you want.
Assuming, then, that the output should never rise beyond the required, regulated potential, your problem lies at the regulator's input. You require the regulator to regulate, always, and therefore you should aim to prevent its input potential from exceeding some maximum.
Since you are using outboard pass transistors to boost current, which won't be subject to the same voltage constraints as the regulator itself, whatever clamping you implement needs only to limit the regulator's own input voltage, not the voltage applied to the outboard collectors. It need pass only the current that the regulator passes, which according to R16 would be:
$$ I_{REG} = \frac{0.7V}{22\Omega} = 32mA $$
That's such a small current that it's fairly trivial to clamp potential at the input side to some maximum. Below is a simplified version of your own circuit, with a clamp to ensure that \$V_B - V_A < 26V\$:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The clamp is implemented with Q4, Q5, D1 and R6. Q4 and Q5 form a darlington pair emitter follower. A darlington pair allows us to keep zener diode current tiny, because we don't want the regulator output to sink anything significant. As the voltage across D1 rises rises past 27V or so, the base of the emitter follower gets stuck at \$V_B + 27V\$, not rising any further, and the emitter will stay at \$2 \times V_{BE}=1.4V\$ below that. Even when D1 isn't clamping, the base of Q5 is held at the highest possible potential by R6, keeping \$V_A\$ as high as possible.
Here this behaviour is plotted as I sweep V1 source voltage upwards to +60V. Blue being the potential difference \$V_B-V_A\$, and orange is output \$V_{OUT}=+5V\$, loaded by a constant 1A of current:


Great solution to my problem, thanks Simon. FYI, I discovered the hard way (after burning up a few regulators) that the TIP30C’s VBE can be as high as 1.3V, and as you know it doubles the current.
Thanks again

I have  bread-boarded up the circuit and it works as you have shown. But I ran into a curious problem.
The regulator draws more current then it should and in effect gets very hot when using a linear PS. I tried a different linear PS with the same result. Then I used a switching power PS, and the regulator behaved as it should, workings as designed with no issues at all.
My question is, what is affecting it when powering this circuit with a linear PS?

@mike If anything were to go wrong I would have had money on it being the switcher that provoked it! My first suspicion would be oscillations somewhere; I hope you have a scope. You don't say under what load current the problem arises. Make sure the external pass transistors are doing their job by measuring voltage across R2 and R3. A failure there is the only way I can think of for the regulator to dissipate more than a watt or so.

Thanks I'll look in that

As it turns out it was my input power leads to the circuit. I was using Pomona clip leads for input,, about 28 or 26 gauge wire. I went to a heaver gauge and the ringing stopped. Must have been lead inductance? Thanks for for all the help.

Simon, why did you not include a base resistor (R20) for Q2 & Q3 to the output of the regulator as I did in my circuit?
Also on occasion I have seen my reference voltage (1.25v) on the regulator climb to about 5 volts, any ideas here?
Regulator loading is 1 to 5 amps approx.

@mike That's a good question. Looking at it now, I would say that there should be a resistor there to sink any leakage current from Q1. I do recall trying to strip the design down to a bare minimum for testing, I probably overlooked that. I suspect it would be important when there's little or no load on the output. My first instinct is to sink to ground though, not the regulator output, as R20 does.
